# Do Windows memory optimizers actually work (on Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, memory, performance, optimize

Note: this is ***not*** an opinion based question, and I ***do not*** want any opinion based answers.

Microsoft have had long enough by now to optimize Windows, build in garbage collectors, etc

Does anyone know of a ***scientific*** study, preferably by a reputable technical site or magazine, which shows some advantage of a "memory optimization tool" over just letting Windows 10 do its own thing?

Science, please. Measurements. No "I feel ..."  or "it seems ..."

Comment: Can you provide any article where MS says about "optimizing" Windows memory? AFAIK, every kernel (unix like) has a garbage collection like feature in its memory management section.

Comment: DuckDuckGo for Google for `do windows memory optimizers work`. The [first hit](http://windowsbulletin.com/free-memory-optimizers-for-windows/) says "`Now it is clear that most people suspect the role of RAM optimizers. Even from my personal experience, I can say that most of them do not work as expected.`". I had more authoritative pages before, but closed the browser tabs

Comment: That example link is the very thing my 2nd paragraph warns you about - it's an advert for a product masquerading as impartial advice.

Comment: Lolx :-)   Well, as I said, I did find some tech sites earlier that says it's all nonsense. I was just looking for a definitive answer

Comment: I agree that it could well be a dupe (upvote), but that one was 9 nine years ago & technology advances ...

Comment: Snake oil is snake oil, I'm pretty sure that as a technology memory "optimisers" stopped advancing the day before the first one was released.

Comment: @Mawg You asked if someone knows of a study that shows an advantage to memory optimizers. You've gotten several "no, and there are good reasons to think there will never be any such things". But you insist these well-reasoned answers with citations to the world's top experts on the subject are opinion based. I suspect that no answer will make you happy. You might as well ask for scientific studies that show that the world is flat and reject anyone arguing the world is round and therefore there are no studies as "opinion".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would argue that the article by Mark Russinovich from December 29, 2003,
is official enough as source:
[The Memory-Optimization Hoax](https://www.itprotoday.com/cloud-computing/memory-optimization-hoax).

The opening paragraph says:

> As you've surfed the Web, you've probably seen browser pop-ups such as "Defragment your memory and improve performance" and "Minimize application and system failures and free unused memory." The links lead you to utilities that promise to do all that and more for a mere $9.95, $14.95, or $29.95. Sound too good to be true? It is. These utilities appear to do useful work, but at best, RAM optimizers have no effect, and at worst, they seriously degrade performance.

I would add that Memory optimizers work in one of two ways:

- They call the
  [EmptyWorkingSet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-emptyworkingset)
  Windows API function, forcing running applications to write their working memory to the Windows page file.
- They quickly allocate a large amount of memory to themselves, forcing Windows
  to discard cached data and write application data to the page file.
  They then deallocate the memory, leaving it empty.

Both of these will indeed free up RAM, but while doing so will use computer
resources, CPU and disk, that could otherwise have been used by the executing
processes.

However, what it finally does is only to slow things down,
because the applications will have to get that data from the page file.
Cache memory will be discarded, so Windows will have to get the data
it needs from the hard drive.
Decidedly not a good idea, especially when the system disk is SSD.

But the best argument against these products is that
**there are no benchmarks**.
There are absolutely no benchmarks going one way or another, proving one thing
or another, meaning that nobody ever managed to prove anything
(or didn't bother to).
I'm sure that if any of the many memory optimization products could come up
with a credible benchmark proving effectiveness, they would have done so,
but there is none. QED.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need scientific measurements, just common sense.

The entire industry for "go faster" apps is based on FUD - Fear, Uncertainty & Doubt.
If enough people tell you your computer will be better if you allow them to "optimise" it for you, you will end up believing it.

The first thing most of those "optimisers" do is 'release unused memory'.
Why the heck would you want to do that? The OS keeps that in RAM because based on usage patterns, you are likely to need it again in the not too distant future. It's a guess, but it's a fair guess.
So if it guessed right, there's no need to go back to your drive & re-fetch that data agin, it's right there ready to be used. If it guessed wrong, then it just eventually allows that area to be overwritten by the next app that needs it. Nothing lost, nothing gained.

The is absolutely no gain in 'releasing' that RAM just so it looks like you have more free memory.

Comment: While I totally agree with you, your answer seems opinion, not fact, based.

Comment: Btw, what about unloading DLLs afterthe last app to use them closes? I don't know if Windows does that, but it's an example of what some "optimizers" claim to do

Comment: Why would you need to? What possible gain would there be? It's FUD, nothing more. As I already said, you don't need 'science' you just need a brain. Think about it.